# Awk readline not working on non rooted Android

Tags: android, awk

I have program which is using awk on Android. In one line, I have this command which some input from line

```
`readline | getline line`
```

Code can't be changed, and it has to be like that. Problem is that when I'm running script on non rooted Android, I get this error:

```
(FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: expression for | redirection has null string value
```

With rooted Android, this problem doesn't not occure. Can it be that non rooted Android doesn't have permission to read from line, or is something else? Can any one suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not not sure its standard that AWK is exposed on a non-rooted device. And its bad practice to have such a dependency, because its not guaranteed you can access it. If you are depending on this then you will likely have no option but to convert that awk expression into actual java code likely.

Comment: I'm using my own implementation of awk.